# rolling average and aggregate more than one column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

How do I also aggregate the 'reviewer' lists together with average of 'quantities'?
For a data frame like below I can successfully calculate the average of the quantities per group over every 3 years. How do I add an extra column that aggregates the values of column 'reviewer, for every period as well? for example for company 'A' for year  1993, the column would be [[p1,p2],[p3,p2],[p4]].

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ['A', 1990, 2,['p1','p2']],
    ['A', 1991,3,['p3','p2']],
    ['A', 1993,5,['p4']],
    ['A',2000,4,['p1','p5','p7']],
    ['B',2000,1, ['p3']],
    ['B',2001,2,['p6','p9']],
    ['B',2002,3,['p10','p1']]], columns=['company', 'year','quantity', 'reviewer'])

df['rolling_average'] = (df.groupby(['company'])
    .rolling(3).agg({'quantity':'mean'}).reset_index(level=[0], drop=True))
```

The output currently looks like:

```
| index | company | year | quantity | reviewer | rolling_average |
| :---- | :------ | :--- | :------- | :------- | :-------------- |
| 0     | A       | 1990 | 2        | [p1, p2] | NaN             |
| 1     | A       | 1991 | 3        | [p3, p2] | NaN             |
| 2     | A       | 1993 | 5        | [p4]     | 3.33            |
| 3     | A       | 2000 | 4        | [p5, p7] | 4.00            |
| 4     | B       | 2000 | 1        | [p3]     | NaN             |
| 5     | B       | 2001 | 2        | [p6, p9] | NaN             |
| 6     | B       | 2002 | 3        | [p10, p1]| 2.00            |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `rolling` can not take non-numeric , we need self-define the rolling here

```
n = 3
df['new'] = df.groupby(['company'])['reviewer'].apply(lambda x :[x[y-n:y].tolist() if y>=n else np.nan for y in range(1,len(x)+1)]).explode().values
df
  company  year  quantity      reviewer                             new
0       A  1990         2      [p1, p2]                             NaN
1       A  1991         3      [p3, p2]                             NaN
2       A  1993         5          [p4]      [[p1, p2], [p3, p2], [p4]]
3       A  2000         4  [p1, p5, p7]  [[p3, p2], [p4], [p1, p5, p7]]
4       B  2000         1          [p3]                             NaN
5       B  2001         2      [p6, p9]                             NaN
6       B  2002         3     [p10, p1]     [[p3], [p6, p9], [p10, p1]]
```

Comment: I see. I guess, I have to always make sure the groups are sorted by years for this to work properly. Is there a better way for that?

Comment: @Mina I am not sure , unless we do it without groupby ~ , but keep the dataframe in order is ok right ~ :-)

Comment: This works :) I will wait to see if someone proposes a better solution before accepting yours as the answer.